# Warning: "..used as the name of the previous parameter rather than as part of the selector"

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone

Что это за предупреждение? Погуглил, но так и не понял в чем дело оО

```
 'toOrder' used as the name of the previous parameter rather than as part of the selector
```

Ругается в методе:

```
-(void)httpSetOrder:(NSString*)fromOrder:(NSString*)toOrder:(NSString*)priceOrder:(NSString*)descriptionOrder {
```

Как я понял, нужно как-то по-другому назвать имя переменной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не совсем корректно объявлен селектор, т.к. его сигнатура выглядит таким образом

```
httpSetOrder::::
```

я полагаю вы хотели подобного

```
-(void)httpSetOrderFromOrder:(NSString*)fromOrder toOrder:(NSString*)toOrder priceOrder (NSString*)priceOrder descriptionOrder:(NSString*)descriptionOrder;
```

при этом сигнатура будет такой:

```
-(void)httpSetOrderFromOrder: toOrder: priceOrder: descriptionOrder:
```